# How to process a delayed/lost baggage case?

Tags: airlines, delays, lost-luggage

I traveled with Flydubai today from Karachi (Pakistan) to Istanbul (Turkey). It was a transit flight via Dubai where the planes had to be changed. My wife and I were the only passengers who changed planes from the original flight.

Upon arrival, we did not receive our checked baggage of two pieces. The airline staff told us that the baggage has been left in Dubai due to a short transit time and they've informed Dubai so we'll receive our baggage on the next flight to Istanbul (they have one everyday). They don't guarantee anything and I believe they might have lost it. How can I get the baggage tracked and make sure it arrives the next day?

Comment: Did you fill out a baggage irregularity report? Did they give you a worldtracer reference?

Comment: The explanation sounds completely plausible and most likely your baggage will arrive in Istanbul tomorrow.  I wouldn't think there's much point in doing anything else until then.  I don't see any reason to fear that your luggage is lost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens quite often (although not as often as it used to). Mine was lost probably around dozen times or so. Always made it to me though.

1. You should file a written claim with the airline **right at the baggage claim**. This usually involves signing the custom forms for international flights (the airline would clear the luggage through Customs for you).
2. You should ask whether they will deliver it to your hotel/apartment/home, and insist they do (they usually do, unless it is your fault, such as late checkin). Note that in some countries - Russia, for example - the airline cannot clear Customs for you, so you would have to be at the airport anyway. In this case ask the airline to provide the transportation, or reimburse the transportation costs.
3. You should receive: a) the claim number and b) the local phone number or web site URL where you can check the status of your bag. Some better airlines have an Android/iOS app which you can use to track the bag return.
4. You should also ask if any compensation by the airline is due because of the delay - the rules are complex and may depend on origin-destination and connecting airlines, so self-research might be more difficult here. There are rules that the bag is considered lost (and compensation due) if it is not delivered within a specific number of days - **even if it is found later** - worth asking about this too.
5. If you have travel insurance, call the insurance company and file a claim. They typically give you allowance for delayed luggage, usually $250-500 a day. Note that your spending has to be relevant to luggage loss (i.e. not movie tickets), the reimbursement is not automatic - you have to submit your receipts for approval - and they don't pay if the luggage is delayed on your return trip.