# I was sold 2 flight tickets that apparently were 2 indirect flights

Tags: luggage, connecting-flights, lost-luggage

My mom traveled from Bucharest to Boston to visit me, on Tarom and Virgin Atlantic via London. On the way here we had some problems with check-in but she made it here and so did her luggage. She just left 4 days ago and we weren't able to do online check-in.

We got to the airport and we were told Tarom did not have a contract with Virgin Atlantic (news to us, we bought one ticket with a layover in London). We were told that she would have to pick up her luggage and take it to the transfer desk. She had 2 bags, so I paid them for the extra piece of luggage.

In London she could't locate her luggage and they told her to talk to Virgin, as they had to be the ones to pick it up. She went to them and after about 1 hour and a half they came back saying they couldn't find it. At this point she had to get on her next flight or she would miss it.

In Bucharest she reported her lost luggage. I called Tarom on that day and was told Virgin Atlantic had made arrangements to pick it up and take it to her. She talked to Virgin and everything seemed okay. Calls every day, no news. On the third day, she was told they had no knowledge of the luggage, they never had it and that Tarom is the one that got paid, so not their problem.

I called Tarom again and they said they would look into it but wouldn't promise anything because it wasn't their job: Virgin Atlantic should be contacting them. I called EDreams, the online company that sold me the ticket, and they hung up on me after being on hold for 1 hour. Her luggage is not even lost, but nobody wants to deal with the problem.

What else can I do about this?

Comment: Did your mum fill out a baggage irregularity report and did she receive a reference number? All major airlines use the World Tracer System, which tracks a bag for 100 days and uses the information provided by the traveller about the appearance of the bag as well as the journey history to try to locate it. This answer may help https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77307/how-to-process-a-delayed-lost-baggage-case

Comment: What airlines? And what online ticket vendor?

Comment: Yes, she reported them lost but she is being told she should have done it in London. We got the ticket on EDreams and the 2 airlines are Virgin Atlantic and Tarom

Comment: "Her luggage is not even lost, but nobody wants to deal with the problem." Huh? Then what exactly is the problem? Also, do you have the baggage receipt? What does it say it was checked to?

Comment: Please use comments instead of answers to add details to your question, or use the edit button.  You should use the same account you originally posted from.  It looks like you have two accounts now; you can [merge them](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).  But when you post as an answer, it can make it look like your question has already been addressed, and keep it from getting enough attention.

Answer (score 1):

Because the checked bags were not interlined (Virgin did not agree to transfer them), I would contact Virgin again.  They should be able to see from the ticket number and your mom's boarding pass that two bags were checked, and should be able to track the bags using the information there.

Check the receipt from your online travel agent, and find the e-ticket number.  The first three digits indicates on which airline the tickets were issued.  That can be helpful.